# SQLite or Azure Table Storage

Tags: win-universal-app

Currently, I saw a lot of developers are asking about SQLite with UWP and I had experience by using Azure Table Storage in Windows App Development.
May I ask what is the pros and cons each of them?

Comment: Answer is opinion based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is kind of localdb for UWP app where else azure table storage is cloud storage and it is of nosql type, meaning there is no joins. So different usage scenario here. Go for SQLite if you need localdb for your app. If you need cloud and of nosql type, you can go for table storage